# writing Unicode-aware one-liners in Perl

Tags: perl, shell, unicode, utf-8

What’s the correct way to write Unicode-aware one-liners in Perl? The obvious way:

```
$ echo 'フーバー' | perl  -lne 'print if /フ/'  
フーバー
```

...kinda appears to work on first sight, but this is just an accident: the Unicode is interpreted as bytes as the next example shows:

```
$ echo 'フーバー != フウバー' | perl  -mString::Diff=diff -lne 'print join(" ", diff($1, $2)) if /(.*)!=(.*)/'                                                                                 => 29
フ?[??]バー[ ] { }フ?{??}バー
```

Just using the `-C` flag to set the `STDIN`/`STDOUT` *etc.* to UTF‑8 is not enough by itself:

```
$ echo 'フーバー' | perl -C -lne 'print if /フ/' 
[no output]
```

...because now the text in `-e` is not interpreted as Unicode.

So is this the way to go (assuming a sane LOCALE — that is, one in the form `"*.UTF‑8"`) like this:

```
$ perl -C -Mutf8 [...]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, loading the [`utf8` pragma](http://p3rl.org/utf8) is required to interpret the “`フ`” UTF‑8 sequence in the source code as a character instead as separate bytes.

The Perl `-C` command-line switch and the `utf8` pragma are locale-independent, but the shell’s `echo` command is not.

Comment: What do you mean that `echo` command is not locale-independent?

Comment: `$ LANG=ja_JP.sjis bash␤$ echo -n フ | uniquote -b␤¥x83t␤$ echo -n フ | hex␤0000  83 74` vs. `$ LANG=de_AT.UTF-8 bash␤$ echo -n フ | uniquote -b␤\xE3\x83\x95␤$ echo -n フ | hex␤0000  e3 83 95`

Answer (score 9):

I like to use [`utf8::all`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8::all) if i need to handle unicode

```
echo 'フーバー' | perl -Mutf8::all -lne 'print if /フ/'
```

PS. using `-C` you need also give specific flags too, AFAIK

Comment: [`-C` on its own (not followed by any number or option list) (…) has the same effect as `-CSDL`.](http://p3rl.org/run#*-C-%5b_number%2flist_%5d*)

Comment: Reason for downvoting is? (@daxim: thank you for clearing this out)

Comment: Thanks -- that module looks useful; pity there isn't a similarly simple and clear built-in way to get the same effect.

Comment: @as. i really miss it in core for a while already, so this module came as saver for me

Comment: @as. Note that I’m not the downvoter. However, I would suggest using the core facilities instead of `utf8::all`. It’s not too rough to say `‑Mutf8 ‑CSAD`, and that you know **precisely** what you’re getting. There’s some question of `-Mwarnings=FATAL,all` control, since the `utf8::all` module pretends to try to enforce string UTF‑8, but in fact hides errors from you that the builtin `:utf8` would duly report as an exception used that way. See [the recipes in the Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://training.perl.com/scripts/perlunicook.html) for more brief examples using only core facilities.

Comment: @tchrist, still i don't get your point. Why should everyone invent  wheel again? Module which binds together sensible defaults seems much better approach.

Comment: @wk. It’s not sensible defaults, it interferes with the utf8 warning subcategories, and it hides things from you that you need to know. Plus it’s not part of standard Perl, which pretty much kills it if you’re trying to write something to run under a default Perl installation. You can’t tell somebody to just run your command line. Not useful.

Answer (score 0):

in Windows 7:

```
chcp 65001 
perl -M"charnames':full'" -E "say qq{I \N{HEAVY BLACK HEART} PSGI.}"
```